# view scrollbar for absolute positioned element outside body-top/left viewport

Tags: html, css, document-body

I want to show scrollbar even on an element that can be positioned outside of the left and top viewport, instead of making them disappear.

```
.abs-position {
  position:absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top:-10px;
}
```

This will go outside body viewport:

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/atnc3/28/

if possible only with css.

Comment: Say the document position is 0, 0. the object went outside they origin so you cannot view it unless the are brought inside. You can do a trick by scrolling the document say top 10 and left 50 on page load. By this you can achieve what you are looking for i think. But you need to do it on javascript.

Comment: I believe this is not possible. The document starts at the left top and renders from there.

Comment: I suspect it but i prefer have some confirms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible with traditional methods.

Possible only with javascript moving the body element, a rudimental try using html5 drag and drop:

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
  if($("img").offset().top<0)
    $("body").css("top",-$("img").offset().top);
  if($("img").offset().left<0)
    $("body").css("left",-$("img").offset().left);
}
```

---

```
body {
 position: absolute;
}
#div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
#div1 img {
  position: absolute;
  left:-50px;
}
```

---

```
<div id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"></div>

<img id="drag1" src="https://play.google.com/books/publish/static/images/google-search.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)" width="100" height="100">
```

something like this:

[codepen](http://codepen.io/eparisio/pen/LGNNMX)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by using javascript.

[Is this what you are looking for?](http://jsfiddle.net/atnc3/31/)

use

```
window.scrollTo(10, 50);
```

Comment: should be something that move the viewport instead of the window. Something that reset the windows coordinate to the 0,0 of the element that is out of view.